# How to set value of input box as rupee icon dynamically on focus by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box , i want that when i click or focus on that , a rupee icon should already be there .currently when i click it shows the code as text . please help ....

```js
$("input.amt").focus(function(){
    var rs = "&#8377;";
    $(this).val(rs);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' readonly name='amount' class='amt' value='' />
```

Comment: [**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/VSuvA/74/) might help:

Comment: @Vikrant not worked

Comment: not worked*.. what's the error?

Comment: that rupee symbol created only blank space bcoz its not supported to be written by my pc

Comment: see this: [Rupee font](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-type-new-symbol-of-indian-currency-rupee-using-keyboard/)